# Python routine automatization with sublime text

Tags: python, json, django, automation, sublimetext

I'm using sublime text to make my web-server and i find myself often to write deserrialization from json to objects in a very simillar pattern every time.

```
db_order = model.objects.create(
           $SOMETHING = request_parsed['$SOMETHING'],
           $SOMETHING_ELSE = request_parsed['$SOMETHING_ELSE'],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            = request_parsed[''],
            # etc....
            )
```

so, there is a qustion, is there any way to do this any easier?

P.S. without `eval()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just unpack dict?

```
db_order = model.objects.create(**request_parsed)
```